# Extend Rails has_many Association (replace finder_sql)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations

How do I extend my has_many association by my own method which "returns an array of all the associated objects"? Specifically, my other model has two back-references (src_record_id and dst_record_id) to the main model and I would like to have all associated records where either back-reference points to my main model. The following does not work:

```
class CfrRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cfr_relations, foreign_key: :src_record_id, class_name: 'CfrRelation' do
    def cfr_relations
      CfrRelations.where('src_record_id = :id OR dst_record_id = :id', id: "#{ self.id }")
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

When I run this code, it still uses the standard, generated query:

```
SELECT * FROM cfr_relations WHERE src_record_id = 17
```

but I would like to see:

```
SELECT * FROM cfr_relations WHERE src_record_id = 17 OR dst_record_id = 17
```

I guess, I am trying to overwrite the getter method which - according to other posts - is probably not a good idea. And possibly the Rails association framework is not able to support my problem. It seems that I need to declare two associations and take it from there.

### Update

I solved this issue by defining two associations and a method:

```
class CfrRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :src_relations, foreign_key: :src_record_id, class_name: 'CfrRelation'
  has_many :dst_relations, foreign_key: :dst_record_id, class_name: 'CfrRelation'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :src_relations, :dst_relations

  def cfr_relations
    CfrRelations.where( 'src_record_id = :id OR dst_record_id = :id', id: "#{ self.id }")
  end

...
end
```

This provides - correctly - with the two separate associations plus a method to get records for both associations when needed (e.g. for the index view). When creating or updating records, I need to handle the associations differently anyway.

Comment: It is better to post an answer to your own question instead of editing it into the question itself. That way it is clear to visitors that there is an accepted answer.